# Is there a way to access and control "Remote Devices" section of Chrome Devtools programmatically?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I understand that the Chrome Devtools protocol exposes the Google Chrome DevTools via APIs to be controlled programmatically, and puppeteer provides a Node.js implementation to do so. However, if I am not wrong, puppeteer doesn't allow us to do *everything* that the DevTools protocol can do.

If I want to remotely debug my android chrome browser, like I can do manually, by going to "Remote Devices" section of my DevTools, is there a way to do so bypassing puppeteer? Is there a package that lets us access more core functionalities of the DevTools protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. puppeteer is just a wrapper around the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). To understand how the protocol works, you might want to have a look at [Protocol Fundamentals](https://github.com/aslushnikov/getting-started-with-cdp/blob/master/README.md#protocol-fundamentals), where the basics are explained.

To communicate on this lower level, you can also use puppeteer. Check out the [`CDPSession`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession) documentation, which exposes the "low level" part of the API.

#### Minimal example:

```js
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession(); // creates a "low level" session
await client.send('COMMAND'); // sends the command to the browser
client.on('MESSAGE', () => { /* message from the browser received */ });
```

#### Alternatives

If you don't want to use puppeteer, there are multiple other libraries. The most used one for Node.js is [chrome-remote-interface](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface), which is more low-level than puppeteer. According [to the docs](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface#how-does-this-compare-to-puppeteer):

> chrome-remote-interface [...] is a general purpose 1:1 Node.js binding for the Chrome Debugging Protocol. Use it if you need all the power of the raw protocol, e.g., to implement your own high-level API.

There are also multiple other libraries (also for other languages). You can find a [full list here](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/awesome-chrome-devtools#protocol-driver-libraries).

Comment: This looks like something I can use. Thanks! Would you be able to help me with a list of parameters client.send('COMMAND') would accept? I was only able to find an example on the github repo i.e. await session.send('Animation.enable');

Comment: You find the full list in the [Chrome DevTools Protocol Viewer](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). To give an example, you can find `Animation.enable` [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Animation#method-enable).

Comment: I tried arriving to a solution for this manually. I ran chrome in headless mode and started a debugging session at localhost:9222. While I was able to see events against other devtools tabs like network, memory, audits etc, I didn't see any events for the tab "Remote Devices". Additional debugging showed below error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'discoverUsbDevices' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.eval

When I clicked on the checkbox "Discover Remote Devices"